# Convert KML polygons to lines

Tags: polygon, kml, ogr2ogr, linestring

I've been given a KML file which should consist of linear features (train lines), but for some reason they're all represented as `<Polygon>` types. Each appears to have the right data, from end of the route to the other, but they end up getting displayed with a straight line back to the start.

Is there any simple way to force them back to lines, perhaps using OGR2OGR? Here's an example:

```
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#style013</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            115.964098859778,-32.0315028760304,0 115.964341724802,-32.0317245932987,0 115.964542217656,-32.0319358011368,0 115.964647923659,-32.0321468844092,0 115.964711196528,-32.0324108954529,0 115.964711217686,-32.0326220438325,0 115.964689983026,-32.0329599395964,0 115.964552921763,-32.0335405684244,0 115.96437328518,-32.0338573549601,0 115.964109337303,-32.0342690027496,0 115.963761062567,-32.0346703082917,0 115.962335595171,-32.0363701095327,0 115.961522621044,-32.0373097675095,0 115.960730829958,-32.0381861099762,0 115.959991839264,-32.0390940652384,0 115.959601168599,-32.0395797019635,0 115.95828143181,-32.0410895001365,0 115.957225616643,-32.0423352695285,0 115.956159387375,-32.0436127783309,0 115.955378027477,-32.0445207271644,0 115.954839524041,-32.0451331177952,0 115.954227198969,-32.0456821560527,0 115.953108092682,-32.0466006683283,0 115.952590699426,-32.0470123779511,0 115.95217894983,-32.0473714061235,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this turned out to be as simple as text search and replace:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing>
```

to

```
<LineString>
```

and

```
</Polygon></outerBoundaryIs></LinearRing>
```

to

```
</LineString>
```

Comment: Good. I thought you could do it with GDAL and I made a test with `ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select CastToLinestring(geometry) from poly" poly.kml`. The command is ok but unfortunately that SpatiaLite function can't convert polygons into lines https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html#cast

Comment: also from google forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/uW0ENZNzm6E